# Fit as many views as posiible without overlapping

Tags: android, gridview

I want to fit as many textViews( Each of them is clicable and leads to some action, so it cannot be just a signle textview populated with text)  from my set as possible in layout. 
To achieve that, I used following gridview layout

```
  <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dip"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:padding="16dip"
             />
```

[image]
And I get result like on image. It looks like 3 colums of items.
What I want to achive - all those textviews should look like i have single textview with long text.
E.g
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) is what you're looking for.

It wraps content to the next line if there is no space in the current line.